# Running ASP.NET MVC 4 app on IIS 7.5 Locally

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have an MVC 4 application that I can run using IIS 7.5. In the application properties there is an option to create virtual directory I click that button and nothing happens. When I open IIS Manager I do not see my application under Default WebSite.

**UPDATE**: I think I am able to setup the virtual directory. But now when I browse the web site it says "A default document is not configured for the requested URL and directory browsing is not enabled on the server".

Comment: Are you using Administrator Credentials? I've got so many strange behavior when i'm using a non Administrator user. Try to run IIS using the "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: yes I am admin running as admin

Answer (score 0):

You should change the path to your default website in IIS to see if it goes to the right place where your solution is.

Comment: Go to IIS Manager, then select your website and choose 'Basic Settings' then modify the Physical Path.